# SOAP UI not finding WSDL depending XSD files in Spring WS Soap Service

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have a Spring SOAP Web service hosting a WSDL that imports several XSD files. The structure inside WEB-INF folder is as this:

```
WEB-INF
│   spring-ws-servlet.xml
│   web.xml
│
└───Esquemas
    │   composite.xml
    │   Esquemas.jpr
    │   EsquemasApplication.jws
    │   SIAS.wsdl
    │
    ├───src
    │   └───META-INF
    │           jps-config.xml
    │
    ├───xsd
    │   │   hello.html
    │   │   readme.txt
    │   │   SIAS.xsd
    │   │
    │   ├───common
    │   │       CommonInterchange.xsd
    │   │       CommonTypes.xsd
    │   │       IdentifyReply.xsd
    │   │       readme.txt
    │   │
    │   └───interchange
    │           CAEFF.xsd
    │           CSEFF.xsd
    │           readme.txt
    │
    └───xsl
```

I am running the project with IntelliJ Idea Ultimate. The project runs fine, and I can see the wsdl through

```
http://localhost:8080/sias.wsdl
```

but when I try to generate the webservice tests in SoapUI, I get the following error:

```
Error loading [http://localhost:8080/xsd/interchange/CAEFF.xsd]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error:
```

As a matter of fact, when I try that URL in the browser I get a 404 error code.

How can I exactly make the folder ***xsd*** under ***/WEB-INF/Esquemas/xsd/*** available through GET?

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my spring-ws-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.sample"/>

    <sws:annotation-driven/>


    <sws:static-wsdl id="sias"
                     location="/WEB-INF/Esquemas/SIAS.wsdl"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I used an older version to generate jaxb classes and a newer version to generate the SoapUi request. The two versions had slightly different namespaces.

Comment: I have the same issue and try with different versions of SOAP UI. But still giving the same issue. I'm new to spring and not sure about my annotated classes. I can see the WSDL in the browser and try to create a SOAP project with that throwing the error. It is not resolve the imports in the schema files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127894/spring-ws-using-custom-schema-for-soap-faults . Is it possible you to share remaining classes also. Or share the sample project.