# Spring-ws using custom schema for SOAP Faults

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws, soapfault

I am working on creating a web service using Spring-WS. And i am using the validation framework provided by Spring-WS to validate the request. When there are validation errors, the web service returns a SOAP fault with the validation errors in the detail element of the SOAP Fault. **I'd like to know if there is a way we can send a custom response(message with my own schema) instead of a SOAP Fault response?** **If so, i'd be grateful if you can describe how i can achieve this.**

I have checked the idea of extending *PayloadValidatingInterceptor* for this purpose, but this only provides me a way to customize the fault string or the error detail message of the SOAP fault which is not what I want.

Thanks in advance!